# glGenFramebuffersOES fails in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm porting a game from iPhone to Android. I'm using NDK and OpenGLES 2.0.
I'm having a problem with the following code to create a framebuffer with a texture attached that I'll later use to render to it:

```
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &glTextureFrameBuffer);
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, glTextureFrameBuffer);

// attach renderbuffer
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, glName, 0);

GLint status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if(status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    cout << "Framebuffer completed" << endl;
} else {
    cout << "Framebuffer error: " << status << endl;
}

// unbind frame buffer
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

cout << "CREATED FRAMEBUFFER ID: " << glTextureFrameBuffer << endl;
```

This prints the following:

```
Framebuffer error: 0
CREATED FRAMEBUFFER ID: 4294967295
```

And rendering to that texture does nothing, so something is failing and the id returned by glGenFramebuffersOES (4294967295) makes me think that the framebuffer is never generated.

The code is working perfectly on iOS.
Any idea what could be the problem?

**EDIT:**

I added error ckecking: I'm getting GL_INVALID_OPERATION after glFramebufferTexture2D.
<strike>But I'm also getting GL_INVALID_VALUE error after glGenFramebuffersOES. The strange thing is that on iphone I get that error too but everything works anyway.</strike>

I've read the OpenGLES docs and glGenFramebuffersOES sets GL_INVALID_VALUE error if the first parameter is negative, wich is not the case.

**EDIT 2:**

My bad, glGenFramebuffersOES is not setting any error, GL_INVALID_VALUE was being set somewhere before.
But still, glFramebufferTexture2D is setting GL_INVALID_OPERATION, and it also seems weird to me that the id returned by glGenFramebuffersOES is 4294967295.

Any idea?

Comment: _Add error checking_. Even if the code works on iOS.

Comment: Added error ckecking: I'm getting GL_INVALID_OPERATION after glFramebufferTexture2D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `glBindFramebufferOES` instead of `glBindFramebuffer`? OpenGL ES 2.0 has framebuffers in its core spec, not in OES extension (like OpenGL ES 1.0 have).

You are already using `glFramebufferTexture2D` function not `glFramebufferTexture2DOES`, right?
So use the `glGenFramebuffers` function and also `glGenFramebuffers`.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is wondering why `glGenFramebuffersOES()` isn't working, I don't think it's supported in OpenGL 2.0 for Android.

If you remove the explicit version setting in Android, `setEGLContextClientVersion(2);`, it should allow you to call `GLES11Ext.glGenFramebuffersOES()`. However, you then lose all ability to use the GLES20 library.

This is based on my guess because when you call `checkIfContextSupportsExtension(gl, "GL_OES_framebuffer_object");` using the code below:

```
private boolean checkIfContextSupportsExtension(GL10 gl, String extension) {
    String extensions = " " + gl.glGetString(GL10.GL_EXTENSIONS) + " ";
    return extensions.indexOf(" " + extension + " ") >= 0;
}
```

It will return false if client verison was set to 2